# Showing $\sigma(A_1)=A_2$

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ is an infinite set then we define
$\newcommand{\comp}[1]{{#1}^{\mathsf{c}}}$
\begin{align}
A_1&=\{A \subset\Omega:A \text{ is finite or }\comp{A}\text{  is finite}\} \\
A_2&=\{A \subset\Omega:A\text{ is countable or }\comp{A}\text{  is countable}\}.
\end{align}
where $\comp{A} = \Omega\setminus A$ denotes the complement of $A$ in $\Omega$

**Exercise**$\;$ Show that $\sigma(A_1 )=A_2$.

**My solution**:
As first step I will show $\sigma(A_1)\subseteq A_2$:

Let $B\in A_1$

1. Suppose that $B$ is finite then $B\in A_1 \Rightarrow B\in A_2$
   $$\sigma(A_1) \subseteq \sigma(A_2) = A_2$$
2. Suppose that $\comp{B}$ is finite then $\comp{B} \in A_1 \Rightarrow \comp{B}\in A_2$. Since $A_1$ is an algebra also $B\in A_1$.
   $$\sigma(A_1) \subseteq \sigma(A_2) = A_2$$

---

Second step showing $A_2\subseteq \sigma(A)$

Let $B\in A_2$

1. Suppose that $B$ is countable then
   $B = \{a_1,a_2,\ldots\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty  \{a_n\}\in \sigma(A_1)$

   $$A_2\subseteq \sigma(A)$$
2. Suppose that $\comp{B}$ is countable then
   $\comp{B} = \{b_1,b_2,\ldots\} = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty  \{b_n\}\in \sigma(A_1)$.
   $B = \comp{\comp{B}}\in \sigma(A_1)$
   $$A_2\subseteq \sigma(A)$$

$\mspace{17cm}\square$

Is that true? If it's wrong please let me know what is true.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can anyone help me?

Comment: Honestly, none of this after "Here my solution" is making any sense. First line, first mystery: how a condition such as $$B\subseteq A_1$$ could be even relevant? You seem to be confusing subsets of $\Omega$ and classes of subsets of $\Omega$.

Comment: Hmmm... I now see you already received an answer on the page this one duplicates. Thus, not much to add, sorry.

Comment: I tried to make your solutions more readable and correct some mixups. I hope you understand the changes.

Comment: Actually, I am in totally trouble. Can you suggest any book or any page for about this topic?

Comment: I think you need to wait until my changes are peer reviewed otherwise you can't see them. This topic is the very basic of measure theory so I think every elementary measure theory book will cover that. Where do you get your information so far?

Comment: One of your confusions is that $A_1$ is a set of sets therefore you have to regard elements of $A_1$ which are also sets

Comment: You seem to using $\overline A$ to denote $\Omega \setminus A,$ which is not standard notation.

Comment: Thanks for your interest @NathanaelSkrepek . I think I have to more study about measure theory...

Comment: You are welcome ;) do you understand the edited proof now? There are some points where one can be a little bit more rigorous.

Comment: My only problem was, in fact, with the notion of "countable". Since you specified it, your proof is correct.